# Enabling OpenMP tool with callbacks in a C++ code

Tags: c++, callback, clang, openmp

I'm developing a small OpenMP tool library that will allow me to utilise OpenMP callbacks. This library is written entirely in C. I can compile and link it into my user code. To compile the library I use the following commands in a `Makefile`:

```
CC     = clang
CFLAGS =-O3 -fopenmp
LDLIBS =-lomp

libompt.so: counter.c ompt.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC $^ -o $@
```

To compile my little example statically or dynamically I have these targets in the `Makefile`:

```
test_daxpy_sta: counter.c ompt.c daxpy.c test_daxpy.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@

test_daxpy_dyn: daxpy.c test_daxpy.c libompt.so
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -L. -lompt $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@
```

All works nice and well. Now I would like to use a C++ object and its methods inside OpenMP `on_ompt_callback_thread_begin()` and `on_ompt_callback_thread_end()` callbacks. To achieve that I need to compile my little OpenMP tool library with a C++ compiler. The only change to the commands above is:

```
CC     = clang++
```

Compiled with `clang++` the OpenMP tool no longer works. It does not register callbacks and does not do any "profiling" work behind the scenes. I do not know why. What is a correct way to enable an OpenMP tool with callbacks in a C++ code?

I compiled my library and static and dynamic executables with `clang` and `clang++`. Then I used `ldd` on my library and the executables. The only difference is that `test_daxpy_sta` compiled with `clang++` uses `libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1`. Is this right? Shouldn't `clang++` rely on an LLVM equivalent of `libgcc_s`? I found `clang++` option `--rtlib`, but I don't know, what is LLVM's counterpart of GNU's `libgcc_s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenMP runtime loads a tool by searching for a globally-visible function with the name `ompt_start_tool` **[1]**. If you are compiling your tool with a C++ compiler, make sure this function is declared `extern "C"` so the function's name is not mangled and can be found by the OpenMP runtime **[2]**.

You can check whether the `ompt_start_tool` function has been mangled using the `nm` command to see the symbols defined in your compiled library:

> `nm libompt.so | grep ompt_start_tool`

As an additional tip for diagnosing the loading of OpenMP tools, you can use the `OMP_TOOL_VERBOSE_INIT` environment variable to diagnose problems with detecting and loading tools at runtime **[3]**. This shold help you verify whether the runtime is able to find and load your tool at all.

#### References

**[1]** https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu177.html

**[2]** https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#call-cpp

**[3]** https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpse77.html